# Terminal doesn't work anymore: _p9k_init_params:72: character not in range manjaro%

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, gnome, manjaro, character-encoding

I'm on Manjaro GNOME. I installed this package from AUR via Add/Remove Software: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/github-desktop/

It told me that I need to restart as it /installed/reinstalled some kernel modules or something. Now my default gnome-terminal does not work. I cannot open it.

When I try to open it either via keyboard shortcut or an icon, it tries to start but never shows up. I can see it as a process, it shows up for a second in my System Monitor and then just disappears.

I installed another (Deepin) terminal. When I open it, that's what I get:

```bsh
_p9k_init_params:72: character not in range                                                                   
manjaro%
```

The same also happens with alacritty terminal.

The GNOME terminal had ZSH and a lot of emojis, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem after a recent update. I am no expert but I guess something wrong with the locale settings. I fixed it by regenerating the locale settings as shown [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale):

Open a terminal with `Ctrl + Alt + F3`

In `/etc/locale.gen` add/uncomment

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

then run with sudo:

```
locale-gen
```

Then my gnome terminal is functional again.

Answer (score 0):

Manjaro Gnome after installing updates and rebooting I could not open terminal and after installing deepin terminal I got the above message.

After searching on the web for answers this is what fixed it:

1. Back up your `.zshrc` if its not already in the `.zshrc.bak` and delete the `.zshrc` file
2. Install deepin terminal from your package manager
3. after opening deepin terminal type:

   ```
   echo en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   echo en_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8 | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   sudo locale-gen
   ```
4. Reboot your PC
5. After the reboot your terminal will open but it looks very much vanilla.
6. Please check if you have a `.zshrc` file if not create one or just paste the one you backed up or copy the contents of `.zshrc.bak` into the new `.zshrc` file.
7. `source .zshrc`